# Recover Fat32 which was wrongly formatted to Mac Journaled Disk

Tags: mac, filesystems, sd-card

A Photocamera with default FAT32 formatted SD card was used and works in camera. It worked with Windows which can read and write the SD card. Someone plugged the card into Mac and formatted it to Mac extended journaled format.
[image: Mac journaled] But never wrote data on it.

Now the SD Card does not show any picture / JPG anymore in Mac. And Windows says "device needs to be formatted first".
Is there any chance how to get most of the picture / data back?

For example format to FAT32 and try to undelete data by using special recovering tools.

Thanks for your experience

Comment: If it hasn't been overwritten you'll have pretty good luck with a standard data recovery/undelete tool. Plug it back in to Windows and run one of those tools. There are free ones and paid ones. Do not attempt to do any further formatting or changes on the drive. Once the data is recovered, reformat it with the proper FAT32 file system.

Comment: There is no tool which allows recovering a "non formatted drive" as I know about. Can you recommend anything?

Comment: It's beyond the scope of this forum to do software suggestions. But most of the tools do recover "non formatted" drives. Being formatted is not a requirement. Scan "by disk" or "partition" instead of by drive letter.  Do a long scan, or deep scan, etc. Recuva and FileScavenger are both what I have used, and I know FileScavenger does this. Just find the right option, it's there.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It helped me to find out, that the SD Memory itself seems to be defective. That is the reason why no recovery software can find more than 32MB on that 64GB card and as soon as the software will try to access the card (even for formatting) it will loose the card completely. Tested as Admin with Windows and Mac. Always with same result, no valid access to card possible.